# PrometheusMetricsServlet is jakarta.servlet but I need a javax.servlet version

Tags: servlets, prometheus

I have Struts hello world project I want to scrape metrics for total request count and response time for each APIs.

Struts Version - 2.5.25 (this is thus still `javax.servlet` dependent)
Java Version - 11.0.21

For that I am following this link
https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/1.0.x/examples/example-exporter-servlet-tomcat/src/main/java/io/prometheus/metrics/examples/tomcat_servlet/HelloWorldServlet.java

To Register a servlet in web.xml I am using this https://prometheus.github.io/client_java/exporters/servlet/

This is working fine for me. But this work only for `jakarta.servlets` what if I want to use it with `javax.servlet`. I am not getting any [PrometheusMetricsServlet](https://prometheus.github.io/client_java/api/io/prometheus/metrics/exporter/servlet/jakarta/PrometheusMetricsServlet.html) for `javax.servlet`. So I am not able to register `javax.servlet`.

For `jakarta.servlet` I am using following depedencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>prometheus-metrics-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>prometheus-metrics-instrumentation-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>prometheus-metrics-exporter-servlet-jakarta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which depedency/version I should use for `javax.servlet`?